# Remmina successfully connects but window closes

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp, remmina

I'm trying to connect from my local ubuntu 18.04 with remmina installed to my remote ubuntu 19.04 where I installed the xrdp server.

It is able to perform the login, but as soon  as it tries to open the window with the remote desktop, the window suddenly closes.

I can't understand why this is happening since I am not getting any error.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL & thus off-topic.  http://ubuntu-news.org/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   Your 19.04 box should be fully-upgraded, then *release-upgraded* to 19.10 asap.

Comment: Look at the logs with `sudo journalctl --since="- 10 minutes"` on each system.

Comment: I solved it, it was just a stupid problem: I cannot login from the local system with the same user account which is already log on the remote system.

Comment: Instead of creating a profile and connecting in remmina, try connecting from the input box directly (vnc protocol worked for me), first few attempts may fail, but it will connect in few attempts.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it: I cannot login from the local system with the same user account which is already log on the remote system.

Comment: I took hours another day trying to figure the solution out. This one worked immediately on Xubuntu (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)